# I will arrange for the manuscript to be sent on to you

Tags: grammaticality

Are all the following expressions correct? What are the differences?

- I will arrange for the manuscript to be sent on to you.
- I will arrange that the manuscript will be send to you in time.
- I will make sure of the manuscript to be sent to you in time

Comment: Only the first is correct. The second has issues with _will be send_ and the third with _of_

Answer (score 2):

*I will arrange for the manuscript to be sent (on) to you (note that "sent on" suggests it is going via other people first)

*I will arrange for the manuscript to be sent to you on time ("in time" may mean "when I get around to it", suggesting it is not important to the sender [see comments])

*I will make sure that the manuscript is sent to you on time

The differences, of course, now that the sentences are grammatically correct, are that the last two mention that they will be sent on time (ie, so that they will arrive by the necessary time). The first does not have this time element, although the suggestion is that it will be done within a reasonable amount of time.

I would suggest you use the English language learners stack exchange for such questions in future:
https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For US usage, at least, "in time" in this context means "in plenty of time" (i.e. with time to spare). We do still use rarely it in the sense of "when I get around to it" but only when something else signals that interpretation.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the clarification! I've been a long time out of North America :)

Answer (score 2):

> - *I will arrange for the manuscript to be sent on to you.*
> - *I will arrange that the manuscript will be send to you in time.*
> - *I will make sure of the manuscript to be sent to you in time.*

*Arrange* can take a number of complements, all of which are noun phrases, and some of which are clauses. Some of the noun phrases require *for*, but some of the *for*'s are part of the *for...to* infinitive complementizer.

- *I will arrange (for) it*.  (pronoun)
- *I will arrange the details.* (noun)
- *I will arrange **for** you **to** go early.*
  (infinitive; *for* marking subject and *to* marking verb are normal for all infinitives)
- *I will arrange **for** it **to** be sent on*. (infinitive)
- *I will arrange for your going early.*
  (gerund; *for* is governed by *arrange*)
- *I will arrange for what you want.*
  (embedded question; *for* is governed by *arrange*)
- *I will arrange that it be sent on to you.*
  (untensed *that* clause; no *for* allowed)

*Make sure (of)*, however, has different affordances than *arrange (for)*.